# Item text is running off page out of margin

Tags: formatting, text

See the last item provided in the code section, and how it shows up on the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{description}
      \item{1e)}
      \item{P_{(maker, city, highway)} := \Pi_{maker, city, highway}(Pickup \bowtie Product) \\ }
      \item{C_{(maker, city, highway)} := \Pi_{maker, city, highway}(Car \bowtie Product) \\}
      \item{$A_{(maker, city, highway)}$ := P \cup C \\}
      \item{A - \Pi_{highway1, city1}(\sigma_{0.55\,city1\,+\,0.45\,highway1\,<\,0.55\,city2\,+\,0.45\,highway2})\rho_{maker, city1, highway1}(A) \times \rho{maker, city2, highway2} \newline
    (A) - \sigma_{highway1 < highway2}(A)) \\ }
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: error]

Update: changed env to 'description' it says ERROR: End  invalid in math mode.

I also get errors saying 'Missing $ inserted'

Comment: That's much better thank you, but `1e` isn't a standard environment is it? Have you defined it yourself? Sorry to be a burden, this'll all be old hat to you after a few posts, but it's really important to learn to begin with, could you complete the document with the preamble you're using, a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`? In other words, please provide a full MWE (Minimal Working Example): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: `\item` does not take an argument, you are missing a lot of math markers, those ``\\`` are not relevant, what is the `1e`  env? Never heard of it. Please provide a fully compilable minimal minimal example where we do not need to guess half the document

Comment: Is that all you have, don't you get errors from that? You should get

``! LaTeX Error: Environment 1e undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6   \begin{1e}
                
? 
``

Comment: Oh sounds like I can't string begin with any name I want. I need to use a predefined env? I'm just trying to separate by the question number and give them each a label. In this case, the problem is '1e'. Yes there are tons of errors.

Comment: It's alright, don't worry, we'll get it fixed, but please don't edit in improvements to your original code as it moves the goal posts for us and changes or removes the problem you need us to fix!

Comment: Oh ok gotcha... also the formatting must be off because if I don't put the '\\' at the end, then all the items run together on the same line

Comment: Is your capital Π a product symbol, or just a Π?

Comment: it's a projection symbol for relational algebra. I really just need to fix the spacing issue, i'm fine with the $ errors... gotta get this homework assignment finished :/

Comment: The way tex recovers from errors, after an error you should not really even _look_ at the generated pdf, certainly no need to ask about any particular way it looks. It just recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the docuemnt, it makes _no attempt_ to make sensible typeset output. So your question should be about the first error `! Missing $ inserted.` not about the margins (which will fix themselves once you fix the errors)

Comment: "fixing the spacing issue" is exactly the same issue as the `$` errors. the spacing is wrong as math mode is being used incorrectly and TeX gives errors about that.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well for not I'm just gonna do a hacky workaround and break into multiple items until I have more time to learn Latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX. I mean this with all the best will in the world, but this was a very hard challenge for me, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do and would recommend you consider changing some of your formatting, as this isn't very friendly on the eye. Nevertheless, I've had a go at giving you what I think you want.

The first thing to say is that in LaTeX, we have lists. We do not number our questions by hand, we use environments. The go to environment is the enumerate environment.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Milk
  \item
  Eggs
  \item
  Cheese
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Gives us a numbered list. LaTeX takes care of all the numbering for me, so that if I decide I want cheese before eggs, I simply change the order in my source code and don't have to go back and redo the numbering.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Milk
  \item
  Cheese
  \item
  Eggs
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

It also does all of the formatting for me, like indentation. Each `\item` increments the counter and moves me on to the next item in my list.

You should never hand number your lists, this is a cardinal sin, punishable by immediate cessation of chocolate rations.

Lists can be nested so that we can have sub-items.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Milk
  \item
  Cheese
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Cheddar
    \item
    Edam
  \end{enumerate}
  \item
  Eggs
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

LaTeX has the style of the labels pre-defined. There's a hard way of changing them, and an easy way, using the `enumitem` package. I've chosen the easy way.

Now, in your case, you seem to have a question 1, with sub questions. For this reason I've used nested lists, so that you can have question 1a), 1b), 1c) ... 2a) 2b) 2c), with LaTeX doing all the numbering.

This can cause some headaches, as you can see that LaTeX usually indents sub-items progressively. This is fine if you have a structure like:

[image]

But looks silly if you have a structure like this:

[image]

Because the margins are too big.

So I've tried to take that into account when defining your list structure.

As for your actual maths, I've done my best, but it's hard to work with. Text should ideally be upright, and I've used `amsmath`'s `\text{}` command for real text. Things like city1 I've interpreted not as text, but as some kind of variable, but I still think it should be upright, so have used `\mathrm{}`. There's probably a lot more that can be done. But this is it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={}]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,start=5,label=\arabic{enumi}\alph*)]
    \item
    \begin{flalign*}
      P_{\text{(maker, city, highway)}} &:= \Pi_{\text{maker, city,
          highway}} (\text{Pickup} \bowtie \text{Product}) \\
      C_{\text{(maker, city, highway)}} &:= \Pi_{\text{maker, city,
          highway}} (\text{Car} \bowtie \text{Product}) \\
      A_{\text{(maker, city, highway)}} &:= P \cup C
    \end{flalign*}
    $A - \Pi_{\mathrm{highway1, city1}} (\sigma_{0.55\mathrm{city1} +
      0.45\mathrm{highway1} < 0.55\mathrm{city2} +
      0.45\mathrm{highway2}}) \rho_{\text{maker}, \mathrm{city1},
      \mathrm{highway1}}(A) \times \rho_{\text{maker}, \mathrm{city2},
      \mathrm{highway2}} (A) - \sigma_{\textrm{highway1} <
      \textrm{highway2}}(A))$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've flushed the equations to the left because I think that works better when they're in a list, however in spite of everything I've said, this is probably not at all the best technique. Instead, have you considered using headings to separate the questions.

Comment: Wow very thorough and useful post. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlexElkman That's alright, you should be aware that this will generate an overfull `\hbox`, but it's very hard for me to do anything about that, because I don't know what exactly you're trying to produce. Personally, I'm not familiar with this field, so this may be the standard notation and you're stuck with it, but if you can switch out whole words in your subscripts for variables that might make things a bit easier to read and write?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't guess from the markup what it was intended to look like, but this could be a start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{1e)}%??

\begin{align*}
      P_{(\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{\mathrm{city}}, \mathrm{highway})} &:= 
\Pi_{\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city}, \mathrm{highway}}(\mathrm{Pickup} \bowtie \mathrm{Product}) \\
C_{(\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city}, \mathrm{highway})} &
:= 
\Pi_{\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city}, \mathrm{highway}}(\mathrm{Car} \bowtie \mathrm{Product}) \\
A_{(\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city}, \mathrm{highway})}&:= P \cup C \\
A - \Pi_{\mathrm{highway1}, \mathrm{city1}}\\
\qquad(\sigma_{0.55\,\mathrm{city1}+0.45\mathrm{highway1} <0.55\,\mathrm{city2}+0.45\mathrm{highway2}})\\
\qquad\rho_{\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city1}, \mathrm{highway}1}(A) \times \rho{\mathrm{maker}, \mathrm{city2}, \mathrm{highway2}}\\
    (A) - \sigma_{\mathrm{highway1} < \mathrm{highway}2}(A)) \\ 
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely use this as a reference. Gave other solution the 'check' because it was a bit more thorough, but I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AlexElkman this solution, with a `\tag{1e}' within the environment might give a more consistent look.